# Smoothing an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, smoothing

I have a depth image which is in uint8 so, contains only discrete number of levels. Is it possible to change the image to uint16 and smooth the gray scale values between the step of the original image. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If it is because you have `banding`, it is often enough just to go to 16-bit and add a little noise to "blend/smooth over" the `banding` effect.

Comment: I have updated the question with a sample depth image file. As you can see it is very discrete. What I want to do is to increase the number of grey scale levels and smooth it.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite difficult because basically you are trying to create information that isn't there, so it is necessarily going to be guesses and approximations since you can't recreate something you didn't capture.

I think the term to Google would be "posterisation", and/or "posterisation removal". One way is to add a little noise to "blur" or "smear" the boundaries. That approach doesn't work very well for your image. Another approach is to "blur" the image using a box blur or Gaussian blur - that kind of works and the image is "smoother" but it is also "blurrier".

Here I have added some Gaussian blur, with a radius of 4 pixels. As you can see, the image is smoother, but blurrier :-( I have also added the `before` and `after` histograms, and you can see there are more tones in the "smoothed" image but it is always going to be a trade-off.

[image]

**Initial histogram**

[image]

**Final histogram**

[image]